The back piece of my kitchen drawer came off and this is where its suppose to be and also some photos of it. What can i do to repair it?




The back piece of a kitchen drawer came off a few weeks ago. I'm a novice in home repair but I'm hoping I can repair this without much difficulty. What would be the best approach in regards to fixing this? I have super glue and caulk but would i need any special wood or anything for the sides?

What you have there looks like an extremely cheaply made drawer. The material appears to be MDF, assembled with an insufficient amount of glue and staples. When it tore free, it also partly split the shelf back.
The quick and dirty fix would be to roughly reassemble it, drill two or three pilot holes through each side into the back, and run screws into those holes. The fact that the backboard has split, however, complicates this. You would first want to close that gap by injecting a proper wood glue into the crack and clamping the crack closed until the glue sets. If some glue squeezes out when you clamp it, just wipe it away; this is not fine furnishing and you aren't going to be finishing this piece.
Note that neither super glue nor caulk is appropriate for this purpose. If you can't get a real PVS wood glue, Elmer's glue-all would be my second choice. Caulk tends to sit on the surface rather than soaking in to form a good bond, and super glue works best on smooth, non-porous surfaces.
Once that piece is repaired, the proper way to reinstall it would be to scrape the mating surfaces clean of the old glue, apply new glue, put the piece back in place, clamp tightly until the glue dries, and then perhaps still drill pilot holes and drive screws since this will be a weal joint without them. But as I said, for this application, I think the screws by themselves will probably outlast the rest of the cabinet unless you are massively overloading that drawer.
For more detailed advice on building and maintaining cabinetry, I would suggest trying the woodworking stack. People there will probably grumble when you mention MDF cabinets, but they are the ones who have the most experience building and repairing drawers. And MDF does have its uses.

Super-glue (cyanoacrylate) is probably not the best fix for this. What I would probably do, particularly since this is in the back so it doesn't have to look so great, is:

Scrape off existing glue
Remove the metal loops. They were part of the original assembly but things will probably not fit together without either removing them (easy - pull out and/or snip them off) or getting them adjusted "just right" (much harder, if possible at all).
Screw the piece to the rest of the drawer. Definitely drill pilot holes and use screws that are fairly long (to grip more of the drawer parts) but relatively thin (to avoid cracking things more than they are already cracked). Note that the bottom of the drawer is likely too thin to hold any screws (it slides into the long slot of the piece that was removed).

Based on the top picture, you still have most of the drawer on the slides in the cabinet. You will need to remove it from the cabinet to do this work properly.
